# iphone background audio on/off

Tags: iphone, audio, background, avaudiosession

I have an application that can play audio while the application is in the background with the entry in the plist and everything work fine.
But I would like to give the option to the user to setup the background play on and off
I use this method to activate the player

```
moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
[moviePlayer play];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]  setActive:YES error:NULL];
```

I would like to change this option on run time and without any interruptions to the audio play.
Any ideas if this can happen?

Thanks for your time

I will post the solution here to make it better

```
if (backgroundSwitch.on) { 
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
}else { 
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Ask to fast :) found the solution                                      `if (backgroundSwitch.on) { 
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
    }else { 
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:NULL];
    }`